Does keeping template strings in my DOM makes it slower?
If I use <script type="text/template"></script> or <template> tag excessively to define large template strings in my DOM, does it make my DOM slower, considering it makes the DOM size larger?
Or maybe, considering it is being treated as a plain text by html parser, it doesn't influence on DOM performace that much?
Also, which is better to use from performance perspective: <script type="text/template"> or <template> tag?

The content of <template> gets automatically parsed by the browser, whereas the content of <script type="any_unknown_script_type"> gets treated as text only.

There's not really a single answer to this. It depends on how complex your DOM structure is, how much content you're putting in to the template, and how often you work with it in your JS.
